# Finding the executed script in response to a command

Tags: ubuntu

I'm learning [ROS](https://www.ros.org/) and I'm trying to dig deep into existing code.

Typical example, *rostopic list*, I need to find what script(s) execute in response to that command and where they are located.

Can anyone advice on commands I can use to accomplish the above ?

Answer (score 0):

If that is a CLI (command line interface) entry, and your shell is Bash, then this command will give you the full name of the command that would be executed:

```
command -V rostopic
```

If ROS is a sensible installation, other  commands in the same package should be in the same location.

This command will show you all the directories that will be searched for any commands, separated by semi-colons. You might recognise parts of the names:

```
echo "$PATH"
```